# How and where can I change GUID for VSTO-Excel-Ribbon?

Tags: excel, vsto, guid

How and where can I change GUID for VSTO-Excel-Ribbon ?
Is it possible in the Project, or after installing ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of which GUID you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

> Generate a GUID:

1. Open your solution with Visual Studio..
2. From VS menu -> **Tools** > **Create GUID**
3. Select **4th option**
4. Click **Copy**

> Edit the YourProjectFile.csproj / or ..vbproj

1. Right-click on your solution's start-up project
2. Click on **Open Folder in File Explorer**
3. When Windows Explorer comes up, Right-click highlighted file
4. Open With -> (choose your text editor)
5. Select the GUID inside the   tags
6. CTRL+V to paste
7. Remove the { } symbols
8. Save and Close
9. At the VS prompt, select Reload

---

...and you're done!

This is how your file might look like with the key you need to change:
[image]